# Database MySQL N:N relations

Tags: mysql, database, schema, entity-relationship

i'm doing a database for the gestion of motor championship, how can i solve this problem??
I have 3 entity(Pilots, Teams and Events) and 3 relations N:N that form a triangle....

[image]

Comment: This is traditionally done with a mapping table for each N:N.  However, does the Pilots<->Events relation actually exist, or can you figure it out from the Pilots<->Teams<->Events relationship?

Comment: Pilot must has a team for partecipate to an event.
 
Pilots(PilotID,....)
Teams(TeamID,....)
Events(EventID,....)

TeamPilot(TeamID, PilotID)
Partecipate(PilotID, TeamID, EventID, Time)

Is right this?? Or i can use The entity 'TeamPilot' with the entity 'Events'??

Answer (score 1):

```
Pilots(PilotID,...)
Teams (TeamID,...)
Events(EventID,...)

TeamPilots(TeamID,PilotID)
TeamEvents(TeamID,EventID)

PilotEvents(PilotID,EventID)
```

Not seeing the why of the last one unless a pilot can participate in an event without being a member of a team.

Comment: yes sorry, the pilot must have a team, without a team he can't partecipate

Comment: Not triangular N:N then, so you don't need PilotEvents